# Integrate a PHP script and an IPhone application?

Tags: php, iphone, ios

I'm developing an application for a School project.So i'll try to explain in a properly way:

I have a php script that allow the user to search in a MYSQL table for some keywords,the code is bellow:

```
<?php


//get data
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];


$s = $_GET['s'];
if (!$s)
$s = 0;


$e = 10; // Just change to how many results you want per page


$next = $s + $e;
$prev = $s - $e;




 if (strlen($search)<=2)
  echo "Must be greater then 3 chars";
 else
 {
  echo "<br /><table><tr><td><img src='juzzy.jpg' /></td><td><form action='search.php' method='GET'><input type='text' onclick=value='' size='50' name='search' value='$search'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'></form></td></tr></table>";

  //connect to database
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  mysql_select_db("content");

   //explode out search term
   $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

   foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
   {

        //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1)
     $construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    else
     $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

   }

  //echo outconstruct
  $constructx = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";

  $construct = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct LIMIT $s,$e";
  $run = mysql_query($constructx);

  $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);


  $run_two = mysql_query("$construct");

  if ($foundnum==0)
   echo "No results found for <b>$search</b>";
  else
  {
   echo "<table bgcolor='#0000FF' width='100%' height='1px'><br /></table><table bgcolor='#f0f7f9' width='100%' height='10px'><tr><td><div align='right'>Showing 1-10 of <b>$foundnum</b> results found for <b>$search.</b></div></td></tr></table><p>";

   while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_two))
   {
    //get data
   $title = $runrows['title'];
   $desc = $runrows['description'];
   $url = $runrows['url'];

   echo "<table width='300px'>
   <h4><a href='http://$url'><b>$title</b></a><br />
   $desc<br>
   <font color='00CC00'>$url</font></table></h4>
   ";


   }
?>


<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center">

<?php
if (!$s<=0)
 echo "<a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$prev'>Prev</a>";

$i =1; 
for ($x=0;$x<$foundnum;$x=$x+$e)
{


 echo " <a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$x'>$i</a> ";


$i++;


}

if ($s<$foundnum-$e)
  echo "<a href='search.php?search=$search&s=$next'>Next</a>";

    }
}  


?>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So i need to integrate this code and an iPhone app,i've already build the for execute the query,its bellow:

```
-(IBAction)executeQuery:(id)sender{

    NSString *encodedValue = [queryValue.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *cont11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/searchengine/searchengine/search.php?search=%@",encodedValue];

    NSData *cont12 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cont11]];

    NSString *cont13 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:cont12 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

    NSLog(@"%@", cont13);

    [queryValue resignFirstResponder];


}
```

So how the app is suppose to work,

1. When the user digit some text on a UITextField and press the button,the code execute the query[THIS PART IS WORKING PROPERLY].
2. After that,the code have to get the results from the PHP and display it on a UITableView or anything UI(can be UILabels)[THIS PART ISN'T WORKING].

My question is:

How can i execute the query and display the results(on a IOS app)?

Comment: What webarto wants to tell you: your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use mysql_real_escape_string to protect yourself: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not send the data as HTML using tables and links etc. but in a different format that is easy to process for a program, e.g. JSON or XML.

I'd go for JSON. Using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) you can encode the entire query resultset. The iPhone app downloads it and decodes it.

Regarding what now has to happen on the iOS side of things: someone else needs to chime in here, I'm not into iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

To build on middus' (and I agree with JSON)...you'll need to add some JSON parser to your project, I use SBJSON. So, you'll format your output as JSON (json.org if you need guidance) and it'll either be (at the highest level) an array or the equivalent of a dictionary. To convert it, you'll do

```
self.myReturnedData = [cont13 JSONValue];
```

*I'm assuming here you've set up myReturnedData as a property, it'll either be NSDictionary or NSArray*

Then, you can set the text of whatever UI element you want...since it's numerous, I'd vote for a UITableView, something like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
    return 52;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TaskCellIdentifier = @"ResultCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ResultCellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ResultCellIdentifier]autorelease];

        UILabel *label;
//you'll need to adjust the following numbers to position as you wish
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 200, 23)];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.tag=999;
        label.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];

    }
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.myReturnedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        return NO;
}
```

But, you'll probably also want to add some buttons or something for pagination